# Understanding python development environments ide's, text editors etc

Tags: python, development-environment

So today I spent hours trying to understand why the package I installed using pip install in terminal was giving me an "module not found" error. Which I know is a file path problem. After a lot of tinkering around I eventually pip installed the library on powershell. Like magic it works. To avoid these headaches in the future and to gain a deeper understanding of all things programming does anyone have a book or class they could recommend to understand the circus of ide's, text editors, file paths, kernals, interpreters, compilers etc. I have no idea where to begin and it's really hard trying to troubleshoot these issues when I've never been given any formal instruction on how all these things work together. Is this something learning a language like C would help me understand? FYI Or does this just take pain and years of experience to navigate. FYI I've only taken a few basic college level python courses.

Comment: This is off topic here insofar as it asks for recommentations.  there is an answerable q. though: would learning C help you use your python ide/env?  Answer: probably not.  You are likely on windows, and dev on windows is just a pain.  What *will* help with that is getting to know the env: how pip works at a high level (it copies files), how python works at a high level (the interpreter reads your code, compiles it to assembly for a virtual machine, and then runs it), etc.  You'll get *that* by finding a few decent books/tutorials/etc on *python* and reading/following them.

Comment: This is a fair question and it's good that you want a deeper understanding of how everything works together rather than just duct tape the pieces together. However, Stack Overflow doesn't do well with open ended questions. For one, the site isn't designed to accommodate back and forth follow-up questions and comments. I recommend you seek out a programming forum. There are many good subreddits such as [/r/learnprogramming](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/) where you can have this discussion.

Comment: I also would *not* recommend starting in c if you are by yourself.  it can be done, but c is much easier if you actually know how the hardware operates (at least at a high level).  For *duration* [read this](http://norvig.com/21-days.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, this has little to do with the programming language. It’s about knowing your way around your operating system. As such it’s not a good SO question; perhaps you should try superuser or one of the OS-specific StackExchange sites.

But what helps is understanding the command line. When you run “pip”, you need to make sure that the program pip - which is just a Python script - is being run by the same Python interpreter that you’ll be using later when you try to import the module.

Basic advice: find all the “python” and “python3” executables on your system. Pick the one you want, or install a new one. Either way, make sure that the directory containing it comes before any of the others in your command search path, and both names (with and without the 3) are there and point to the same binary file. That way you always know what you’re getting when you run “python” at the shell prompt. Make sure you configure your IDE to use the same one, too. And instead of typing “pip”, type “python -mpip” so that you know it’s at least installing into the same environment you get when you type “python”.